# puppet node update at will

Tags: deployment, puppet

What is the preferred method (or any for that matter) to tell puppet nodes to update when I make a change to site.pp for instance and need it deployed right away?

I have thought of pssh-ing to the nodes and executing 'sudo puppetd --test' on each one. I was wondering if there are better/other ways to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with enabling "runner" service throug "listen" option in puppet client.

Comment: specifically the puppetrun command on the puppetmaster (or perhaps from elsewhere if you enable it via namespaceauth.conf.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys.  I read the puppetrun man and tried a few things to no avail.  To set this up all I need to do is add namespaceauth.conf allowing connetions in [puppetrunner] and on the client setting listen = true from within [puppetd] right?  And then of course run puppetrun --host from the puppetmaster.

did I leave anything out that I must do to set this up?

Comment: Think I found the problem.. There is a bug in puppetrun 0.24.5 that prevents it from working. see: http://projects.reductivelabs.com/issues/1500